# Using rm for a file in a directory

Tags: linux, makefile, console, command, rm

I'm new using the linux commands and I'm having a problem using the rm command in a makefile.

The makefile is in the **/project** directory and I want to remove all the files with extension .o that are in the **/project/src** folder.

I have tried with

```
rm /src/ -f *.o
```

and

```
rm /src -f *.o
```

I do not receive any error in the console but it does not delete the files either.

Could someone please help me?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Read documentation: [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html), [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html), [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). Also provide some [MCVE] (e.g. some simplified `Makefile`, if you believe your bug is there)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete files like this

```
rm -f src/*.o
```

-f is to force deletion, without confirmation

Answer (score 0):

You can use: rm -f /projects/src/*.o

Comment: Using an absolute path in a Makefile probably is dangerous/unexpected and might result in unintentionally deleted files.

Comment: Thanks!, It works. I just needed to put -f before the path